# SlamData install Linux

Tags: linux, slamdata

does anyone know how to install SlamData on linux? I've download the file on my machine, and double click it, but it opens a green screen and nothing happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Download the linux installer file;

add executable permission

```
chmod +x slamdata_unix_2_1_8.sh
```

Run the executable and follow instructions;

```
./slamdata_unix_2_1_8.sh
```

After installation, To start SlamData, cd to your installation dir, issue the following command;

```
./SlamData
```

For further documentation visit http://slamdata.com/documentation/